# Rewrite only if file exists and it is a GET request

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am developing a PHP CMS and am currently implementing a static file cache. The idea behind the cache is, that all pages are compiled to html and then simply served by apache or nginx. The problem is, if it is anything else than a GET request it should still get rewritten to the PHP CMS and not directly served. This is my current htaccess config, I stripped the HTTPS redirect.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it, but only if it is a GET request
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But as soon as I send a POST request it fails with a error 500. The apache error log shows the following message:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://jinya.local/contact
AH00121: r->uri = /index.php, referer: http://jinya.local/contact
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: http://jinya.local/contact
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: http://jinya.local/contact
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: http://jinya.local/contact
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: http://jinya.local/contact
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: http://jinya.local/contact
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: http://jinya.local/contact
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: http://jinya.local/contact
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: http://jinya.local/contact
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /index.php, referer: http://jinya.local/contact
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /contact, referer: http://jinya.local/contact
```

Can someone help me figure out what the issue is?

Comment: Everything except `GET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last rule creates an infinite rewrite loop.

Workaround: don't apply the rule on your base index

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```